# Gaussian blurring with OpenCV: only blurring a subregion of an image?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Is it possible to only blur a subregion of an image, instead of the whole image with OpenCV, to save some computational cost?

**EDIT**: One important point is that when blurring the boundary of the subregion, one should use the existing image content as much as possible; only when the convolution exceeds the boundary of the original image, an extrapolation or other artificial border conditions can be used.

Comment: How to do it in Python?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To blur the whole image, assuming you want to overwrite the original (*In-place filtering is supported* by [cv::GaussianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur)), you will have something like

```
 cv::GaussianBlur(image, image, Size(0, 0), 4);
```

To blur just a region use [Mat::operator()(const Rect& roi)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#id6) to extract the region:

```
 cv::Rect region(x, y, w, h);
 cv::GaussianBlur(image(region), image(region), Size(0, 0), 4);
```

Or if you want the blurred output in a separate image:

```
 cv::Rect region(x, y, w, h);
 cv::Mat blurred_region;
 cv::GaussianBlur(image(region), blurred_region, Size(0, 0), 4);
```

The above uses the default `BORDER_CONSTANT` option that just assumes everything outside the image is 0 when doing the blurring. 
*I am not sure what it does with pixels at the edge of a region*. You can force it to ignore pixels outside the region (BORDER_CONSTANT|BORDER_ISOLATE). SO it think it probably does use the pixels outside the region. You need to compare the results from above with:

```
 const int bsize = 10;
 cv::Rect region(x, y, w, h);
 cv::Rect padded_region(x - bsize, y - bsize, w + 2 * bsize, h + 2 * bsize)
 cv::Mat blurred_padded_region;
 cv::GaussianBlur(image(padded_region), blurred_padded_region, Size(0, 0), 4);

 cv::Mat blurred_region = blurred_padded_region(cv::Rect(bsize, bsize, w, h));
 // and you can then copy that back into the original image if you want: 
 blurred_region.copyTo(image(region));
```

Comment: Seems that this method does not take care of the boundary -- it still uses some sort of interpolation instead of what is really in the image outside the region. Am I right about this?

Comment: @xuhdev you are right. I have added an example to my answer to get around this. If the region might be near one or two boarders of the containing image, you will need to add some messiness to cope with that.

Comment: @xuhdev, upon looking at the filter engine code, I now think that maybe you are not right. Need to test.

Comment: I can see your edited solution. Yes, it works, but the actually it has blurred some unnecessary region which leads to extra work. Any way, have you tested the original method yet? Does it actually uses the border in the original matrix?

Comment: Doing this in parallel_for_ gives runtime error. I have disjoint stripes of images in different threads.

Answer (score 11):

Here's how to do it in Python. The idea is to select a ROI, blur it, then insert it back into the image

```
import cv2

# Read in image
image = cv2.imread('1.png')

# Create ROI coordinates
topLeft = (60, 140)
bottomRight = (340, 250)
x, y = topLeft[0], topLeft[1]
w, h = bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0], bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1]

# Grab ROI with Numpy slicing and blur
ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(ROI, (51,51), 0) 

# Insert ROI back into image
image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = blur

cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Before `->` After

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to blur a Region Of Interest in OpenCV.

```
size( 120, 160 ); 
OpenCV opencv = new OpenCV(this);
opencv.loadImage("myPicture.jpg");
opencv.ROI( 60, 0, 60, 160 );
opencv.blur( OpenCV.BLUR, 13 );   
image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );
```

For more information, check out this [**link**](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/opencv_blur.html).
Good luck,

Comment: BTW, the question had a C++ tag. The C++ solution has a rather different form to that for Java.

Comment: @B... For me it doesn't matter. It's easy to translate from one language to another.

Comment: Didnt even notice at first, but glad i could help

Comment: I believe it can be, I can look over my old openCV projects and ill let you know @JoãoAbrantes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using javacv provided by [bytecode](http://bytedeco.org)

then you can do like this way. It will only blur particular ROI.

```
Mat src = imread("xyz.jpg",IMREAD_COLOR);
Rect rect = new Rect(50,50,src.size().width()/3,100);
GaussianBlur(new Mat(src, rect), new Mat(src, rect), new Size(23,23), 30);
```