# Using OpenCV, how to blur a part of an image?

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am using `inRange()` function of `OpenCV4Android` to detect a colored blob in an image. Then I am using `drawContours()` to draw the contours around the selected object.

What I want is that when the contour is drawn, the image *outside* the contour (i.e. the part which is not a part of the contour or detected colored blob/object) should get a little blur.

How can I do that? I am not asking necessarily for code. If you can tell me what function(s) to use, or how to go about it, I'll look into the API's and do it. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: did you try the gaussian blur?

Comment: I guess gaussian blur on a sub region would work .  see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195138/gaussian-blurring-with-opencv-only-blurring-a-subregion-of-an-image

Comment: @shaheen I have seen the gaussian blur method but I don't know how to apply it to parts other than the region of interest.

Comment: @shaheen Thank you for that link. They have given `image(region)` as the first argument to the `GaussianBlur` function, where `region` is the region-of-interest (like the area inside the contour). I don't know I would give that kind of argument in OpenCV4Android :s

Comment: I guess a much easier way would be to apply the blur by using the renderscript available in Android. PS: I haven't tried it .  But seems a sturdy option.  https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript    , http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

Comment: @shaheen Thank you so very much indeed, but this seems more complicated, since I need to blur out the image outside the contour (i.e. _outside_ the orange ball), and not the entire image. I don't think Android has any concept of ROIs (Region Of Interest). :(

Comment: I think the solution may be to blur the complete image, and only afterwards combine the blurred and the original image using a mask which is generated by the area defined by your contour (using a function like bitwise_and). I could only give you a opencv python solution if you dfon't know how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am going to try it in Java/Android, then I'll tell you =)

Comment: @tfv do you mind helping me with the solution to this in python? i'm having the same problem. i have what i want to keep in focus stored as rectangle coordinates and I to blur everything else, but i don't know how to get stuff like bitwise_and working right. 

can you take a look at my gist please?
https://gist.github.com/stanchiang/b4e4890160a054a9c1d65f9152172600

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one it is in python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/home/user/Downloads/lena.png")
blurred_img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (21, 21), 0)

mask = np.zeros((512, 512, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
mask = cv2.circle(mask, (258, 258), 100, np.array([255, 255, 255]), -1)

out = np.where(mask==np.array([255, 255, 255]), img, blurred_img)

cv2.imwrite("./out.png", out)
```